# Conditional execution block with || and parentheses problem

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

So this should be simple. I am trying to test a condition at the top of a script and bail out of the entire script when the condition fails, and I have two statements I want to execute when I bail. With a lone `exit` and no second statement, it's fine, but no matter how I add a second statement, I can't get it to completely exit. The implicit cosmetic rule is that this must be all on one line. I discovered this when this one-liner change to a script did not work as intended. The script kept going.

First let me show what *does* work.  The following line completely exits if the $USER variable isn't 'x', and that's good.  I know this works because typing this line into a  terminal window will close that terminal window (unless your user id really is 'x'), so it's really doing a top-level exit:

```
[ $USER = 'x' ] || exit 1
```

So this is good and just as I want, except I want to echo a message before exiting; however, if I try to add the echo, the exit no longer occurs or rather it seems to occur "differently," like perhaps in a bash function context or something.  The next line will *not* close your terminal, and this is bad.

```
[ $USER = 'x' ] || (echo "Time to bail" ; exit 1)
```

I thought maybe the semi-colon was getting eaten by echo, but no, the exit does seem to be getting hit. How do I know? I changed the code above and then echoed $? and I saw whatever value I put where you see "1" above. And of course I was viewing these values in a terminal window that I wanted to be closed, and it wasn't closed.

The next variation also shows a second way to perform an echo and a second statement, but again the exact same behavior occurs when an exit is used:

```
[ $USER = 'x' ] || (echo "Time to bail" && exit 1)
```

I'm hoping someone here is going to make this all not only not strange but sensible-seeming.

So is this not possible to do on one line?

(`bash --version`: `GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release`)

Comment: `! true || { echo false; exit 1; }`

Comment: @mikeserv, OK, I think that's working.  Why does it need curly braces?

Comment: I see it now, I just found [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html). The parens are creating a sub-shell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're searching is something like this:

```
[ "$USER" = "x" ] || { echo "Time to bail"; exit 1; }
```

The `{ list; }` statement executes the commands in the given list in the current shell context. No subshell is created, unlike in the `( list )` notation. An `exit` call between parentheses will exit that subshell and not the parent shell itself.

---

The examples in your question with the if-statement on one line or multiple lines are syntactically correct. I cannot reproduce that behavior. It doesn't matter how many lines there arre; the if-statement never starts a subshell in its body.

---

BTW: I added double quotes to the variable in the condition, because when the variable `$USER` is empty, the construct would expand to `[ = "x" ]` which is not valid. With double quotes it expands to `[ "" = "x" ]`.

Comment: It's my fault...  I have a mistake up there in the if. It should be a not condition. Oops. The parens was the main question though....

Comment: @user62177541 Are you sure that the condition is true? I ask this because the main problem was about `condition || command` -> if `condition` is **not** true then `command` and the second problem is `if [ condition ]; then command; fi` -> if the `condition` is true then ...

Comment: The curly braces seem to require a lot of semi-colons.  Annoying. Also, the && form is now illegal syntax with the curly braces.

Comment: @user62177541 You only needed semicolon is the one behind the last command (but it can also be a newline).

Comment: OK, I guess this is another version having only one semi-colon:  `[ $USER == 'x' ] || { echo Time to bail && exit 1 ; }`

Comment: @user62177541 Yes, that works too. But its exits only then when the echo command is successfully.

Comment: Right, but does a hardcoded string echo ever fail?

Comment: @user62177541 Probably not, but i thought the echo stands for some other command...

Comment: @user62177541 - `echo` never fails. `echo` is a true.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @mikeserv's hint, the answer is extraordinarily simple and it has to do with the importance of recognizing that parentheses present a very special kind of grouping. Parentheses create a sub-shell, and that is exactly why I was seeing the lack of what I called a "top-level" exit.

A complete explanation is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html), and here's the key excerpt:

> Placing a list of commands between parentheses causes a subshell environment to be created...
>   Placing a list of commands between curly braces causes the list to be executed in the current shell context.

What is a bit unpleasant here though is that the two are not completely interchangeable and the curly braces require a semi-colon before the final curly while the parentheses do not. The syntax I am settling on tries to eliminate the semi-colons and use the "&&" form:

[ $USER == 'x' ] || { echo "Time to bail" && exit 1 ; }

So all in all, the parentheses are nicer to look at than the curlies, and the curlies with their semi-colon requirement make the one liner look less like a one-liner.